# Check end of directory?

Tags: android, directory

I'm trying to come up with a simple file explorer for a user to select a folder for preference for my application. Is there any way to check/detect for end of directory?

Comment: have you tried anything? show us some of your code and point to your problem.

Comment: please try explain your question/problem/requirement so other can be sure abt that and answer relatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean to say if there are no sub directories in the CWD?

```
File[] dirs = currentWorkingDir.listFiles();
boolean noDirs = true;
 for(File ff: dirs)
{
   if(ff.isDirectory())
   {   noDirs = false;    break; }

}
```

If `noDirs == true` there are no sub-dirs

Answer (score 0):

```
String path="/sdcard/any directory name/";
    file=new File(path); 
//check directory is exists
    if(!file.exists())
    {
  //if not exists then create new directory

      boolean success = (
                  new File(path)).mkdir();
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.